# How can I determine whether a given SSD and motherboard are compatible?

Tags: motherboard, ssd, sata, computer-building

How can I determine whether a given SSD and motherboard are compatible?

For example, I have an OCZ Vertex 2 OCZSSD2-2VTX50G 2.5" 50GB SATA II MLC Internal Solid State Drive and a GIGABYTE GA-H67A-UD3H-B3 LGA 1155 Intel H67 HDMI SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 ATX Intel motherboard.

Comment: You can treat an SSD like a normal HDD for purposes of 'Will it be recognized'.  So basically SATA is SATA 99% of the time.

Comment: okay thanks! I'm going to use a 2TB HD for multimedia and the SSD for applications. (if it all works together)

Comment: I hope you're using the SSD for your operating system too. ;)

Comment: definitely! its a 50GB ssd and from what i'm told windows 7 is around 20GB. so it should work. other than the operating system, i really only use fl studio 9, guitar pro 6 and AOE 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, SATA1/2/3 are backwards/forwards compatible with each other (with some exceptions, [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#SATA_1.5_Gbit.2Fs.2C_SATA_3_Gbit.2Fs_and_SATA_6_Gbit.2Fs)).