# Ssd in 945 chipset motherboard

Tags: ssd, motherboard, sata

I am thinking of buying a ssd for my old desktop.
The ssd I will be buying is Gigabyte 120gb internal ssd.

I have a 945chipset motherboard with SATA II support.

I would like to know if the ssd will be compatible with my motherboard and if there will be any performance issue.

Comment: Yes it work but at Sata II speeds.

Comment: And the speed is?

Comment: Wouldn't the 945 chipset affect the sata II speed?

Comment: http://ixbtlabs.com/articles2/mainboard/i945-i955-chipsets-specs.html

Comment: I run an SATA III SSD in an SATA II build. It's OK, really - certainly compared to spinning rust. I'd say 120 is too small though. You'll spend your entire life trying to keep 20GB free space & never quite succeeding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I determine whether a given SSD and motherboard are compatible?](https://superuser.com/questions/256389/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-given-ssd-and-motherboard-are-compatible)