# How do I know if my SSD is compatible with my motherboard?

Tags: ssd, installation, motherboard, sata

So I want to install a Samsung SSD (860 Evo 1TB 2.5 inch SATA III MZ-76E1T0B/AM) into my MSI motherboard (Z170A Gaming M5). My motherboard has SATA III and the SSD is SATA III. Am I all good? Or are they not compatible? Help.

Comment: If you have a SATA connection you are 100% fine. Compatibility issues only happen if you have a non-SATA connection on the motherboard like an NVMe connection. And the biggest headache there? Just make sure you get the right drive for the NVMe connection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I determine whether a given SSD and motherboard are compatible?](https://superuser.com/questions/256389/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-given-ssd-and-motherboard-are-compatible)

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine because old and new SSD are SATA III. I put a 2 TB Samsung 860 SATA III drive in my Lenovo ThinkCentre a year ago, reinstalled Windows 10 with my Recovery USB, restored my data and documents and installed my apps. All well one year later